# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kafka'

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have downloaded Kafka and installed kafka-python library using "pip install kafka-python" and "conda install -c conda-forge kafka-python".

I am able to run "from kafka import KafkaProducer" inside a python shell on the terminal. But the same line shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kafka'" on Jupyter Notebook.

I would be thankful for any help on how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Is the library being installed into the same environment in which it is being imported?  *Usually* this problem statement appears when a library is (unknowingly) installed into a different from which it is being used.

Comment: And, arguably more importantly, why are `pip` *and* `conda` being used to install?  This is only asking for background issues. Stick to one or the other.  (At the risk of throwing a personal (experience-based) opinion; dump conda and stick to `pip`.  If you need virtual environments, use `virtualenv`, and save the headache that is Anaconda.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added a screenshot showing the environment. I am unable to understand if it is installed into the same environment in which it is being imported.

I tried first with pip. When it didn't work, I tried with conda.

Comment: Pick a Python version. `python3.9 -m pip install ....` for example. You can see in your screenshot that you're installing with pip from Python 3.11 but attempting to use from Python 3.9.

Comment: Thank you, I will also try installing with python3.9.
For now, I tried using virtual env, it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall Jupyter from the *Homebrew's* Python (Python 3.11), rather than run it from your system's python (Python 3.9, which you would have had to use `sudo pip install`, which is wrong)

You should not need both conda and pip to manage packages.

Then, install packages *outside* of Jupyter

e.g.

```
python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install jupyterlab kafka-python
jupyter-lab
```